# Kotlin multiplication between nullable and non-nullable float errors even with null check

Tags: kotlin

I'm porting a class called `ShapeData` from Java which is filled with nullable types. It looks like this:

```
class ShapeData {
    var type: Shape.Type? = null // Circle, Edge, Polygon, Chain

    // PolygonShape / ChainShape
    var vertices: FloatArray? = null
    var offset: Int? = null
    var len: Int? = null

    // setAsBox
    var hx: Float? = null
    var hy: Float? = null
    var center: Vector2? = null
    var angle: Int? = null

    // CircleShape
    var radius: Float? = null
    var position: Vector2? = null

    // EdgeShape
    var v1: Vector2? = null
    var v2: Vector2? = null
}
```

These properties are nullable because they are read from JSON and might not exist, and since certain fields allow negative values `-1` is not a valid default.

Certain properties need to be scaled if they exist so for that I'm converting a previously static method to a Kotlin top-level function, however I've run into a bit of an issue:

```
fun scaledShapeData(data: ShapeData, scalar: Float): ShapeData {
    return ShapeData().apply {
        type = data.type
        vertices = data.vertices?.map { it * scalar }?.toFloatArray()
        offset = data.offset
        len = data.len
        hx = if(data.hx != null) data.hx * scalar else null // This is marked as an error with "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied" message
    }
}
```

The precise message i get is this (image since Android Studio doesn't let me select and copy the message):

[image: kotlin warning/error message]

I've also tried to replicate this in the Kotlin playground with this piece of code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var test1 : Float? = 2f
    val test2 : Float = 2f

    var test3 : Float? = if(test1 != null) test1 * test2 else null

    print(test3)
}
```

And this compiles and outputs 4.0 as expected. As far as I can see the two code samples are near identical.

What exactly am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// This is marked as an error with "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied" message
hx = if(data.hx != null) data.hx * scalar else null
```

The difference between your playground example and this example is that `data.hx` may change *between* the `null` check and the multiplication.

You can use the following instead, using the `times` function on `Int`:

```
hx = hdata.hx?.times(scalar)
```

since `*` is [translated to `times`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#binary-operations).